# RMarkdown and YAML not able to load packages

Tags: r, yaml, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown

I have a text that I want to convert from latex to Markdown for various reasons. But I'm not able to make it work. If I load all the packages and only type "yo" as text, it's returning me an error.

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a directive at line 5, column 1could not find expected directive name at line 5, column 2
Calls: <Anonymous> ... yaml_load_utf8 -> mark_utf8 -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Many people had this error before but I haven't saw somebody encountering this error so far and a solution for packages like this.

1. Can we write comments "%" in the preamble?
2. How can I add my latex packages in RMarkdown?
3. Will it work if I export it in word?

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "rest"
author: "Me"
date: '2016-10-26'
header-includes:
% Titles
   - \usepackage{titlesec} 
% figure
   - \usepackage{color}
   - \usepackage{graphicx} % Enhanced support for graphics
   - \usepackage{subfig} % subfigure environment
   - \usepackage{float} % Improved interface for floating objects
   - \usepackage{rotating} % Rotation tools, including rotated full-page floats
  % \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % Customising captions in floating environments
% tables
   - \usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Driver-independent color extensions 
   - \usepackage{array} %  Extending the array and tabular environments
   - \usepackage{longtable} %  Allow tables to flow over page boundaries
   - \usepackage{multirow} % Create tabular cells spanning multiple rows
% math
   - \usepackage{amssymb} % some weird math symbols
   - \usepackage{amsthm}
   - \usepackage{amsmath} % AMS mathematical facilities for LATEX
% documents aspect
   - \usepackage{lineno} %  Line numbers on paragraphs
   - \usepackage[top=2.2cm, left=2.2cm,right=2.2cm,bottom=4.2cm]{geometry} % Flexible and complete interface to document d=imensions
  % see geometry.pdf on how to lay out the page. There's lots.
   - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Accept different input encodings
   - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   - \usepackage{lscape} % Place selected parts of a document in landscape
   - \usepackage{babel}
% reference in text
   - \usepackage[unicode=true, pdfusetitle, bookmarks=true, bookmarksnumbered=false, bookmarksopen=false, breaklinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}, backref=page,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
   - \newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}
% bibliography
  %\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex} % Bibliographies in LATEX using BibTEX for sorting only
   - \usepackage{natbib} % Flexible bibliography support
  % \usepackage{translation-natbib-fr} %French translation of the documentation of natbib
  %\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
  %\bibliography{yo.bib}
  % \ref{} makes reference to a \label{} set in a table or figure
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
   - \theoremstyle{plain}
title: "data"
author: "Me"
date: '2016-10-26'
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
documentclass: article % - \documentclass[english]{scrartcl
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
YO
````

Answer (score 1):

Your header contains invalid YAML, inline comments need `#`:

```
---
title: "rest"
author: "Me"
date: '2016-10-26'
header-includes:
# Titles
   - \usepackage{titlesec} 
# figure
   - \usepackage{color}
   - \usepackage{graphicx}
...
```

You'll also need to de-duplicate your YAML map keys. Sure, you can render RMarkdown to Word with the obvious caveat that LaTeX-specific formatting won't automagically carry over.

Comment: The only problem I have now is that in my new command `- \newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}` I have pound `#` signs. This makes them as comments, but I don't want to. Is there a way to treat them in a different way? At the same time, I get many other error messages from the packages I load: `! Undefined control sequence. l.86 \theoremstyle` or `! Argument of \paragraph has an extra }. <inserted text> \par  l.1276 \ttl@extract\paragraph` or `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.` etc. But when I run them in LaTeX, it's fine...